# ANDROID Share information between my own app via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I'd like to share information between my own app running on 2 different phones via a bluetooth intent.

Lets say i have some data on `phone a`, then i will tap *synch* and it will start the same app at `phone b` (if it's not already open) with a bundle containing that "data".

My app on `phone b` acts acordingly.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if this is what you're looking for.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("image/jpeg"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileLocation)); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Image"));
```

This intent shows all available options for file send such as Email and Bluetooth. Choose Bluetooth and the device initiates bluetooth discovery.

Thanks!

Comment: i would be sending a custom type or serialized stream, the main idea is to synch SQLite databases between 2 running instances of the app on different phones, doing this could i catch the file sent on the receiver phone?

Comment: your intention is still unclear. well, once you have the file ready to be sent, you can transfer it to other phone via bluetooth.

Comment: thanks again Renjith how would i implement the code for receiving the bluetooth file on my app? intent filter?

Comment: your answer has the sending code, id also have to implement a code in some part of my app to receive the incoming bluetooth and do things with it, where would that be done?

Comment: have you checked that in Bluetooth Chat sample application?

Comment: SORRY i didnt realize it was you who answered, i think with this and the bluetooth chat i'll manage to do it! thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, it is not possible.
Use BluetoothSocket and BluetoothServerSocket instead

Comment: could you explain a little bit more how to do it this way?

Comment: Please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw this interesting video about NFC, and i know you are talking about bluetooth.
but watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=49L7z3rxz4Q#t=768s 

*Timestamp added, starts at: 12:48*.

What they did is starting the app trough nfc but probably they send the data trough bluetooth. Its really user-friendly.
In this way you do not need to push the button sync but just bump eachother phones together!

I hope this helps you maybe further,

Daniel

Comment: thanks i came across this too, but unfortunately my app is intended to lower versions of android

Answer (score 0):

I think you must make use of BluetoothServerSocket to accept incoming connections. Exchange data with server once connected. To get started check out this doc.

[Start-up](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

You could find the source code in your SDK. Download samples from Android SDK manager. Select 'Samples for SDK' from the required SDK version.

Go to

```
<location of android-sdk>/samples/<version>/
```

Open 'Bluetooth Chat' application. It has almost everything you need.

Thanks!

By the way, don't forget to accept the answer!